# drop sql database vs dropping all tables

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

after some advice.

I'm using MSSQL, and have a process that requires a clean slate each run.  The current process it uses is to drop the database and create a new one.  Every now and then I hit an error about it being in use.  In order to eliminate that annoyance, I am wondering if dropping all tables would be a better method.

What are peoples thoughts on this?

Comment: question is not clear......

Comment: is it better to drop all tables, or just drop the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the database you could simply detach it from the server, and attach a prepared clean database. This means its no longer a T-SQL operation but a server maintenance operation. It might even be quicker.